# How to know MajorityReadConcern set in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

The mongo Document on MajorityReadConcern  is a confusing part for me. I'm running a PSA architecture and in one RS the startup warn shows i need to disable MajorityReadConcern . But in another RS, i dont see the warning.
The document also says its applicable only for WT storage engine. I'm using MMAPv1.

*To use read concern level of "majority", replica sets must use WiredTiger storage engine and election protocol version 1.*

**Mongo Member with mmapV1 not showing startup warning.**

```
[root@RR-sessionmgr01 ~]# ps -ef | grep 27757
root     1740703       1  0 18:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/mongod --ipv6 --nojournal --noprealloc --smallfiles --slowms 500 --storageEngine mmapv1 --bind_ip_all --port 27757 --dbpath=/var/data/sessions.1/20 --replSet set20 --fork --pidfilepath /var/run/sessionmgr-27757.pid --oplogSize 5120 --logpath /var/log/mongodb-27757.log --logappend --quiet
root     1744939 1744203  0 18:09 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 27757
[root@RR-sessionmgr01 ~]# mongo localhost:27757
MongoDB shell version v3.6.17
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27757/test?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("fb657cac-4e00-4518-a5ef-92de55f6f0c9") }
MongoDB server version: 3.6.17
Server has startup warnings:
2021-03-15T18:08:31.604+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2021-03-15T18:08:31.604+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2021-03-15T18:08:31.604+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2021-03-15T18:08:31.604+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2021-03-15T18:08:31.604+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2021-03-15T18:08:46.219+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0]
2021-03-15T18:08:46.219+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] ** WARNING: This replica set was configured with protocol version 0.
2021-03-15T18:08:46.219+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] **          This protocol version is deprecated and subject to be removed
2021-03-15T18:08:46.219+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] **          in a future version.


set20:SECONDARY> db.serverStatus().storageEngine
{
        "name" : "mmapv1",
        "supportsCommittedReads" : false,
        "readOnly" : false,
        "persistent" : true
}
```

**Mongo Member with mmapV1 showing startup warning.**

```
root     2656313 2461367  0 19:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 27717
root     2780840       1  1 Mar11 ?        02:06:20 /usr/bin/mongod --ipv6 --nojournal --noprealloc --smallfiles --slowms 500 --storageEngine mmapv1 --bind_ip_all --port 27717 --dbpath=/var/data/sessions.1/1 --replSet set01 --fork --pidfilepath /var/run/sessionmgr-27717.pid --oplogSize 5120 --logpath /var/log/mongodb-27717.log --logappend --quiet
[root@RR-sessionmgr02 ~]# ps -ef | grep ^C
[root@RR-sessionmgr02 ~]# mongo localhost:27717
MongoDB shell version v3.6.17
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27717/test?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("23754930-8aaa-4eaa-84bf-c41e2e7f548a") }
MongoDB server version: 3.6.17
Server has startup warnings:
2021-03-11T06:16:22.333+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2021-03-11T06:16:22.333+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2021-03-11T06:16:22.333+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2021-03-11T06:16:22.333+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2021-03-11T06:16:22.333+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2021-03-11T06:16:22.409+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0]
2021-03-11T06:16:22.409+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] ** WARNING: This replica set uses arbiters, but readConcern:majority is enabled
2021-03-11T06:16:22.409+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] **          for this node. This is not a recommended configuration. Please see
2021-03-11T06:16:22.409+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] **          https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/psa-disable-rc-majority-3.6
2021-03-11T06:16:22.409+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0]
2021-03-11T06:16:22.409+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0]
2021-03-11T06:16:22.409+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] ** WARNING: This replica set was configured with protocol version 0.
2021-03-11T06:16:22.409+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] **          This protocol version is deprecated and subject to be removed
2021-03-11T06:16:22.409+0000 I REPL     [replexec-0] **          in a future version.
set01:SECONDARY>

set01:SECONDARY> db.serverStatus().storageEngine
{
        "name" : "mmapv1",
        "supportsCommittedReads" : false,
        "readOnly" : false,
        "persistent" : true
}
```

The document says the readConcern:majority is supported only for WT. So why we are getting this warning for mmapv1 storage engine?

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/reference/read-concern-majority/#readconcern.%22majority%22

Comment: So what is your question? There is documentation explaining how to disable majority read concern.

Comment: Apologies, i realized my post was incomplete. with MMAPv1 storage engine is readConcern:majority applicable first of all.? If its not applicable why the warning?

i checked the db.serverStatus() output and it shows the following for both the cases.
``` set20:SECONDARY> db.serverStatus().storageEngine
{
        "name" : "mmapv1",
        "supportsCommittedReads" : false,
        "readOnly" : false,
        "persistent" : true
}
```
But still why the startup warning shows the RS uses readConcern:majority enabled?

Comment: Update your question with the questions, comments are not a replacement for having the question be complete.

Comment: Please have a look on below link once: 
https://www.virtual-dba.com/blog/mongodb-warning-readconcern-majority-is-enabled/

Comment: Thanks for the link @ROHITKHURANA. But my question is why Mongo prints the waring message for mmapV1 storage engine.

Comment: https://docs.huihoo.com/mongodb/3.4/reference/read-concern/index.html#read-concern-storage-engine-drivers

Comment: read concern level of "majority" is not supported for mmapV1 storage engine. Hope above link helped you.